# XCode7 UITests how to test screen edge pan gestures?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I have the following gesture recognizer in my app. I've looked at xCode7 UI and see that it has swipe up/down/left/right, but no pan or edge pan gestures.

**How can one test or initiate screen edge pan gesture for UITesting purposes?**

```
  UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer *leftEdgeGesture = [[UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(show)];
    leftEdgeGesture.edges = UIRectEdgeLeft;
    leftEdgeGesture.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:leftEdgeGesture];
```

Answer (score 15):

I spent a while trying to figure this out, navigating around the element hierarchy. Lots and lots of googling and finding nothing.

I gave up twice, then figured it out.

We just need two coords on the main app screen, and drag one to the other.

Works a treat!

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app launch];

// Set a coordinate near the left-edge, we have to use normalized coords
// so you set using percentages, 1% in on the left, 15% down from the top
XCUICoordinate *coord1 = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.01, 0.15)];

// Then second coordinate 40 points to the right
XCUICoordinate *coord2 = [coord1 coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(40, 0)];

// Perform a drag from coord1 to coord2
// Simulating swipe in from left edge
[coord1 pressForDuration:0.5f thenDragToCoordinate:coord2];
```

Hopefully this will help everyone else who has been struggling to simulate an edge swipe.

Comment: Thanks! Also I've noticed that dragging from the half of the screen height on iPad causes iOS to start multi-window state - have to drag from 20% of the height or so.
It's such a pity that there's no framework method for edge swipes.

Comment: For iOS13 and above, you have to start from 0 for x-coordinate.

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't seem to work if the screen is filled by a `UITextView`. Pressing and then dragging will just move the text cursor.

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on Chris' awesome answer, here's the swift version:

```swift
    func pressCoordinate(x xCoordinate: Double, y yCoordinate: Double, app2call: XCUIApplication=XCUIApplication()) 
    {
        let normalized = app2call.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.01, dy: 0.5))
        let coordinate = normalized.withOffset(CGVector(dx: xCoordinate, dy: yCoordinate))
        normalized.press(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: coordinate)
    }
```