# Is it possible to simulate two finger swipe in iOS UI Testing?

Tags: ios, swift, swipe, gesture, xcuitest

I want to perform a two finger swipe in my UI Test. I am using XCUITest framework. I tried all pinch and rotate methods but Seems like there is no built in support for this functoinality.

Comment: Did you get a chance to check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772202/xcode7-uitests-how-to-test-screen-edge-pan-gestures. Also provide us with what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will work, but you can try to simulate two different fingers dragging screen simultaneously. Something like this:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
[app launch];

// Set a coordinate near the left-edge, we have to use normalized coords
// so you set using percentages, 1% in on the left, 15% down from the top
XCUICoordinate *coord1 = [app coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.01, 0.15)];

// Then second coordinate 40 points to the right
XCUICoordinate *coord2 = [coord1 coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(40, 0)];

// Third coordinate 100 points down from the first
XCUICoordinate *coord3 = [coord1 coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(0, 100)];

// Last one is 100 points down from the second
XCUICoordinate *coord4 = [coord2 coordinateWithOffset:CGVectorMake(0, 100)];

// Perform a drag from coord1 to coord3
[coord1 pressForDuration:0.5f thenDragToCoordinate:coord3];
// Perform a drag from coord2 to coord4
[coord2 pressForDuration:0.5f thenDragToCoordinate:coord4];
```

Comment: This will execute the first swipe first and second swipe after that one by one. We cannot make it happen parallelly.